# Pyspark producing non-deterministic file not found error

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

#### Description of Problem

I'm running pyspark locally on a Windows computer. I'm intermittently getting file not found errors about temporary files. For example, the error shown below is from `df.distinct().count() == df.count()`, but this line of code sometimes works. What could be causing this and how to I solve it?

#### Error Message

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1380.count. :
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
>   Task 3 in stage 289.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task
>   3.0 in stage 289.0 (TID 7751, localhost, executor driver): java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   C:\Users\jbishop\AppData\Local\Temp\blockmgr-36cdf9ca-71ad-4341-ab77-a5b42f4fc6f8\02\temp_shuffle_56a07610-c2c0-4691-b9c8-5f8bae4876c2
>   (The system cannot find the path specified)

#### Versions

pyspark 2.4.5 (conda package)

py4j 0.10.7

python 3.7

Windows 10

Comment: That's an indication of some executor failures, likely some memory issues.

Comment: try limiting your columns in `df.distinct()` rather than applying it on all the columns.

Comment: @user10938362 Do you have any suggestions for how to go about troubleshooting this, assuming it is a memory error?